# Summed-area table for circular range queries

Tags: computational-geometry, image-processing

A summed-area table is a data structure and algorithm for quickly and efficiently generating the sum of values in a *rectangular* subset of a grid [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table)]. Is there any algorithm for quickly and efficiently generating the sum of values in a *circular* subset of a grid?

Comment: I've never heard of one, but I've seen the SAT being used for that too (ie dividing the circle into rectangles). Is that an acceptable approach or do you want something specifically tailored for it?

Comment: Would hexagonal or approximate circle suffice? [like this](http://www.google.com/patents/US6507676)?

Comment: If circular range queries cannot be answered efficiently, octagonal range queries might be a reasonable alternative. Would you like to convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to approximate circle with hexagon or octagon as desciribed in expired patent [US 6507676 B1](http://www.google.com/patents/US6507676). Further improvement is to add rectangles to octagon to get more circular shape or like harold proposed cover the whole circle with rectangles. Unfortunately this defies the core efficiency of summed area table.
The naive way would be to use e.g. Bresenham circle algorithm and sum consecutive rectangles, which by the way is still big speed up, proportional to circle size. The best way is to inscribe square and add rectangles to get finer results. This is illustrated [here](http://yehar.com/blog/?p=1495).

[image]

*Picture taken from http://yehar.com/*

There is no possibility of creating SAT especially for circle even leaving jagged border, simple proof is from impossibility of tesselating space by circles.

Comment: What's the time complexity of this? O(log r) ?

Comment: $\mathcal O(1)$ it is fixed partition (the hexagon and octagon), the rectangles approximating the circle -> depends on the size and accuracy.

Comment: That cannot be correct - the number of rectangles inscribed over the horizontal axis alone increases in r, and hence the number of queries (rectangles) must increase in r.

Comment: Yes, the approximation is in $\mathcal O(\log r)$.